# How to install PowerShell modules for oracle cloud

Tags: oracle, powershell, powershell-module, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Need oracle cloud commands to perform some operations.
for that need oracle powershell modules for that.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Cloud launched OCI Modules for PowerShell yesterday. This link should help you get started - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/powershellgettingstarted.htm

This will allow natively calling OCI Cmdlets from PowerShell to access and manage Oracle Cloud Resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the detailed steps of installing OCI CLI in PowerShell here:
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/cliinstall.htm

Answer (score 0):

@isarecz your link shows how to install oci-cli *with* powershell, unfortunately not *in* powershell.

I think question was more about "is there powershell cmdlets for OCI?", so you can query the OCI API with powershell commands. Answer is : not currently.

Official SDKs and cli are listed here : https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdks.htm

Yet, powershell cmdlets would be a great addition!